# What do we mean by Instance.classname() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

I would like to know what do we mean when we write instanceName.className, in Python.

Like in PyMySQL:-

```
db = pymysql.connect(...)
cursor = db.cursor() <- what does this mean ?
```

Comment: What makes you think that `cursor` is a class name? It's a method.

Comment: well, 'type(db.cursor()).__name__ ' returns 'Cursor' and 'Cursor' which is the name of a class in pymysql

Comment: Python is case sensitive, so `Cursor` isn't the same thing as `cursor`. And anyway, the best way to find out if something is a class is to use `type(db.cursor)`. It's a method that returns a Cursor object, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir ! got it now